# Symbols/methods/funtions for NOR, NAND, or XNOR?

Tags: java, boolean, logic, boolean-algebra

Are there any coding languages (preferably java) that has symbols for NOR (not or), NAND (not and), or XNOR (not exclusive or)?

If not, are there prewritten methods in java or funtions in other languages for such oppertunities?

This question is because a lot of my conditional statements are getting quite hard to read and I want to make it cleaner. I already am aware of the not, and, or and xor symbol.

Comment: No. There is no set of built-in set of the boolean negation operators NOR, NAND and XNOR. There are however NOT, OR, AND, and XOR.

Comment: I suspect having symbols for boolean operators other than the standard would decrease rather than increase clarity for most readers. Perhaps some intermediate variables or methods would be a better option to make your code cleaner.

Comment: Assembly languages contain operations for NOR, NAND and NXOR :)  

In regards to making your Java code cleaner, consider posting code snippets to the code review community: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I'm sure the answer is 'yes' regarding other languages, but not in Java. I once used a variety of Basic that had all kinds of operators including EQV. @ElliottFrisch

Comment: @MarquisofLorne Sure. And I used to play with discrete logic chips where those were very common gates. But Java is mostly positive logic (other than `~` and `!`).

Comment: @ElliottFrisch That's what I'm referring to. I'm sure there are some logic-gate languages somewhere.

Comment: @MarquisofLorne Sorry. "any coding languages".... vhdl I suppose.

Comment: The XNOR of two boolean variables `a` and `b` is simply `a == b`